# How to Fix bottom tab bar when working with listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, android-tabhost

I am making an application in which i am fetching data from JSON into ListView, but whenever i fetch more records into listview my bottom tab bar does not come it hides at that time, but if i have small number of records in listview like:- 3 or 4 item rows only, then i am able to see my records, when i was working with static listview at that point i was not getting the same problem because i was getting both large number of records with Fixed Bottom tab bar, so may i know what could be the problem?

Comment: Check your layout, List view is probably overlapping tab-bar view.

Answer (score 1):

There are following steps you can follow:

1. Use Relative layout.
2. Align bottom bar to the bottom as:

   ```
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   ```
3. set list view above the Bottom bar as:

   ```
   android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBarId"
   ```

It will work with Relative layout only.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

see this, parent layout of list and bottom_bar should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottombar" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottombar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bottom Tab bar"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```